# Time Series Modeling: How to get a more stable time series model that captures postive/negative runs?

Tags: time-series, arima

I am trying to fit a time series to a data set that contains both positive and negative values. A key metric that I need to use to determine the quality of the fit is the distribution of positive and negative runs that the time series simulates.

With an ARIMA model (currently I am using a (5,0,1)), the runs that I simulate are much shorter than those in the data itself. This might mean that my simulations are too volatile compared to the actual data, as the simulations switch between positive and negative values more quickly than the actual data.

How can I get a better fit of the run length behavior of the time series?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Fit a model more like your data?  There's really not enough information here to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Take a simple AR(1) and try different values of the coefficient. A coefficient that is positive and close to zero should give short runs, while a coefficient close to one should give long runs. A negative coefficient close to one should give runs of length 1.